# Make a private reply without "Private message regarding" in the subject line

Tags: google-groups, google-apps-for-work

I am trying to set up a Google Groups collaborative inbox (I have Google Apps for work) to handle emails from the public to members of a team. While playing around, I found that when I select "reply privately to author", Google prepends the words "Private message regarding:" to the subject line.

In there any way to prevent this behaviour?